# How to prevent Furigana (Hiragana put above Kanji) from being copied?

Tags: xetex, pdf, copy-paste, xecjk

The following MWE will generate pages containing Kanji with Furigana. A Furigana is a text put above Kanji to let us know how to pronounce the Kanji.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{ruby}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\setmainfont{Cambria}
\setCJKmainfont{ipaexm.ttf}

\renewcommand\rubysep{.1ex}
\renewcommand\rubysize{.4}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{\ruby{私}{わたし}は\LaTeX が\ruby{好}{す}きです}

\ruby{私}{わたし}は\LaTeX が\ruby{好}{す}きです。
\end{document}
```

## Question

When I compile the MWE and highlight a sentence, I get the following.

[image]

Here, the furigana is also highlighted. Actually I just want to copy the sentence without furigana. How to do so?

Comment: Under Linux with the pdf-viewer evince I have no problem.

Comment: for the title use `\texorpdfstring{title text}{bookmark text}`. then you'll get correct bookmarks, The macro is defined by `hyperref`

Answer (score 1):

Under Linux with the standard pdf-viewer and okular I also have no problems with highlighting.

What about writing your own *ruby* command?! How does look the highlighting with this?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xeCJK}

\newcommand\myruby[2]{
    \begin{tabular}{c}\hskip-5pt\fontsize{5}{5} \selectfont#2\\[-2pt]
    \hskip-5pt\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont#1
\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
    \myruby{私}{わたし}は\LaTeX が\myruby{好}{す}きです。
\end{document}
```

If this works we can think about how to correct the horizontal alignment...

Comment: I am so sorry. It does not help. The furigana is still highlighted.

Comment: Then its a good time to give a linux based OS a chance ;-)

Comment: I don't know how to use Linux. ;-)